# Sliding images in infinite scrollview using nstimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, nstimer

i have three images.Those should be animated from right to left for every 4 seconds like a wheel . if the user drag to 2nd image then after 4 seconds sliding start from 2nd - 3rd onwards. how to implement this?

currntly i am using below code but it is not working as expected.

```
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(doAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)doAnimation
{

    if (currentPage) {

        [self scrollFromCurrentpage];
        return;
    }

    //CGPoint p=CGPointMake(count*320, 0);

    if (count==3) {
        count=0;

        [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)animated:NO];

        return;
    }


    count++;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
     {
         CGRect rect= CGRectMake(count*320, 0, 320, 352);
         [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:NO];

     }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {


     }];
}
-(void)scrollFromCurrentpage
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^
     {
         CGRect rect= CGRectMake(currentPage*320, 0, 320, 352);
         [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:NO];
         currentPage=0;

     }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {


     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a property for your `NSTimer` instance. You should implement a method where you `invalidate` and reset your `NSTimer` instance every time the user scrolls manually.

Comment: give me proper implementation